# MaxLength data annotation is not working on the client side validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have the following model class:-

```
public class DataCenter_Validation
    {


        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] timestamp { get; set; }



    }
```

But the maxlength validation will work ONLY after submitting the form, and it is not having any effect on the client side validation. while the Required data annotation is working both client & server side. Can anyone advice what is wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: You have to use [StringLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx) validation attribute for that.

Comment: why the Maxlenght will not work ?

Comment: Because it doesn't work on the client side. If you want to use `MaxLength`, you need to implement custom data annotations provider and editor templates.